# Preserving cheese sandwich

Tags: bread, cheese

I'm curious about an effective method of preserving a cheese sandwich. I'm looking to prepare them as far ahead of use as possible. I've considered various alternatives but it's not really clear what's best.

- Room temperature- cheese should be refridgerated?
- Fridge- bread and fridges doesn't mix.
- Freezer- pretty long-term, but foods are just not the same after being frozen, and it's not clear if half a working day is enough to guarantee defrosting

So the bottom line is, how can I preserve my cheese sandwich  for the longest time with the least degredation? I like soft bread.

For bonus points, add pickle.

Comment: I've heard stories from my mom & uncles that she would make all of the sandwiches for the week on Sunday, wrap them up and then freeze them.  So they'd thaw in their lunchboxes each day.  I know there was some change in them, as one time she realized that she could've put the Monday sandwiches in the fridge instead of freezing them all.  Personally, I've never liked really soft bread ... I grew up with loaves of American sandwich bread that had already been frozen, or more rustic loaves which we didn't tend to use for sandwiches.

Answer (score 1):

The freezer is your only option. If you don't like the taste after unfreezing, then there is nothing you can do and have to make your sandwiches fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Room temperature is out if you use any spreads like mayo, you'd need to refrigerate them or freeze them, neither of which is good for the consistency of the bread. In either case your bread will be soggy and/or stale. I'd say you could get away with one day in the fridge and still have it reasonably edible, depending on the bread and other factors.

Of course there's always the [Candwich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QbuQS5dNRE)! Talk about yummy ;)!

Comment: Give me yesterday's stale cheese sandwich from the fridge any time before I would even consider that....

Comment: Oh come on @Stephie, surely bread that can last a decade will be all good!

Answer (score 0):

Can you get access to a grill or similar? Switch the problem to 'how can I get my ready-assembled grilled cheese sandwiches to work?' and it's a much easier problem!

I've tried making batches of sandwiches on a sunday night and popping them in a freezer for the week, and it worked OK. I didn't try pickles; I imagine the water content in them, or in tomatoes, would mean it definitely won't thaw in time.